# GLSL Compile Error "gl_Position"

Tags: java, glsl

```
   #version 150 core

   in vec3 position;
   in vec2 textureCoords;

   out vec2 pass_textureCoords;

   void main(void) {
      glPosition = vec4(position.x, position.y, position.z, 1.0);
      pass_textureCoords = textureCoords;

   }
```

ERROR: 0:9: 'glPosition' : undeclared identifier

ERROR: 0:9: 'assign' :  cannot convert from '4-component vector of float' to 'float'

Help please! How can I solve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of the vertex shader is **`gl_Position`** not `glPosition`.

```
gl_Position = vec4(position.x, position.y, position.z, 1.0);
```